# You've lost some text. ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode

Tags: beamer

I got the above error message trying to compile this frame:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}
\usepackage[varioref=false]{chemstyle} 
\usepackage{mhchem,chemfig} 
\usepackage{flowchart} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[lofdepth=2]{subfig}
\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Empirical Framework}
\begin{table}[htb!]
\caption{Previous Studies}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{clcl}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Lerner Index Model results in other studies}\\
\midrule
Author(s)   &   Sample (\# of African countries &   Periods &   Results \\
\midrule
Amidu and Wolfe (2013)  &   55 Developing countries (22)    &   2000-2007   &       \\
Turk Ariss (2010)   &   60 Developing countries (14)    &   1999-2005   &       \\
Beck et al. (2013)  &   79 countries    &   1994-2009   &       \\
Agoraki et al. (2011)   &   13 CEE countries    &   1998-2005   &       \\
Fu et al. (2014)    &   14 Asian countries  &   2003-2010   &       \\
Berger et al. (2009)    &   23 industrialized countries     &   1999-2005   &       \\
Kouki and Al-Nasser (2014)  &   31 African countries    &   2005-2010   &       \\
de Guevara and Maudos (2011)    &       &   1993-2003   &       \\
Aboagye et al. (2008)   &   Ghana   &   2001-2006   &       \\
Weill (2013)    &   22 EU countries &   2002-2010   &       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Offtopic, but inside tables or figures, `\centering` should be preferred to `\begin{center} ... \end{center}.

Comment: Tanx Grill, I have updated the codes as observed. I hope I can get help with this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `chemstyle` does not seem to play nicely with `table`. Thankfully [campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331547/youve-lost-some-text-latex-error-not-in-outer-par-mode/331582?noredirect=1#comment812558_331582) did some digging and found out the culprit is that `chemstyle` loads the `floatrow` package which is incompatible (and does not make sense) with beamer.

So two possibilities:

> 1. Remove `\usepackage[varioref=false]{chemstyle}`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{grffile}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}
%\usepackage[varioref=false]{chemstyle} 
\usepackage{mhchem,chemfig} 
\usepackage{flowchart} 
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[lofdepth=2]{subfig}
\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Empirical Framework}
\begin{table}
\caption{Previous Studies}
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{clcl}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Lerner Index Model results in other studies}\\
\midrule
Author(s)   &   Sample (\# of African countries &   Periods &   Results \\
\midrule
Amidu and Wolfe (2013)  &   55 Developing countries (22)    &   2000-2007   &       \\
Turk Ariss (2010)   &   60 Developing countries (14)    &   1999-2005   &       \\
Beck et al. (2013)  &   79 countries    &   1994-2009   &       \\
Agoraki et al. (2011)   &   13 CEE countries    &   1998-2005   &       \\
Fu et al. (2014)    &   14 Asian countries  &   2003-2010   &       \\
Berger et al. (2009)    &   23 industrialized countries     &   1999-2005   &       \\
Kouki and Al-Nasser (2014)  &   31 African countries    &   2005-2010   &       \\
de Guevara and Maudos (2011)    &       &   1993-2003   &       \\
Aboagye et al. (2008)   &   Ghana   &   2001-2006   &       \\
Weill (2013)    &   22 EU countries &   2002-2010   &       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> 2. Don't use a `table`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{chemstyle} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Empirical Framework}
\captionof{table}{Previous Studies}
\centering
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{clcl}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Lerner Index Model results in other studies}\\
\midrule
Author(s)   &   Sample (\# of African countries &   Periods &   Results \\
\midrule
Amidu and Wolfe (2013)  &   55 Developing countries (22)    &   2000-2007   &       \\
Turk Ariss (2010)   &   60 Developing countries (14)    &   1999-2005   &       \\
Beck et al. (2013)  &   79 countries    &   1994-2009   &       \\
Agoraki et al. (2011)   &   13 CEE countries    &   1998-2005   &       \\
Fu et al. (2014)    &   14 Asian countries  &   2003-2010   &       \\
Berger et al. (2009)    &   23 industrialized countries     &   1999-2005   &       \\
Kouki and Al-Nasser (2014)  &   31 African countries    &   2005-2010   &       \\
de Guevara and Maudos (2011)    &       &   1993-2003   &       \\
Aboagye et al. (2008)   &   Ghana   &   2001-2006   &       \\
Weill (2013)    &   22 EU countries &   2002-2010   &       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Besides this, cleaning up the packages is probably a good idea. You don't need `xcolor` with beamer, as it already provides these functionalities.

Do `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` and `\usepackage{float}` make any sense in beamer?

Comment: @campa To be honest, I don't know what the problem is, I just debugged the MWE. Do you have an answer? Then I will delete mine.

Comment: @campa Don't worry, your question is completely justified.

Comment: I've digged further: `floatrow` (which is loaded by `chemstyle`) apparently doesn't play well with `beamer`, see e.g. [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204148/82917).

Comment: @campa Unfortunately `chemstyle` can not be fooled to think `floatrow` is already loaded :(

Comment: @campa Do you want to write an answer with this explanation?

Comment: Just edit yours; I'm happy I could help.

Comment: Tanx guys, I found your suggestions invaluable

Comment: @Sepfem Good to hear that the answer helped you. If you are satisfied with the solution, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions. As a bonus, this will not only give a reward to the answer, but you will get 2 reputation points, too.